# Oracle JOIN failing

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I'm trying to convert an old style query to ANSI.  Why does the top query fail (Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended) but the bottom version work?

```
SELECT
  JOBS.STARTED_DATE,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.HOURS
FROM JOBS 
JOIN JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS ON JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.JOB = JOBS.JOB 
WHERE 
  JOBS.STARTED_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2013-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  AND to_date('2013-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')

SELECT
  JOBS.STARTED_DATE,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, 
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.HOURS 
FROM JOBS, JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS 
WHERE 
  JOBS.STARTED_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2013-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  AND to_date('2013-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.JOB = JOBS.JOB
```

Comment: What happens if you append a semicolon to both?

Comment: What is your Oracle version? ANSI SQL was not implemented in Oracle until 9i

Comment: It looks like it's the Oracle version problem.  Thanks Dmitry. Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production
CORE 8.1.7.0.0 Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 8.1.7.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 3.4.1.0.0 - Production

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any Problem with any of the above **two** `Query`.

I would suggest to put a **semicolon (;)** as **Mathew Strawbridge** commented.

Like this:

```
SELECT
  JOBS.STARTED_DATE,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.HOURS
FROM JOBS 
JOIN JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS ON JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.JOB = JOBS.JOB 
WHERE 
  JOBS.STARTED_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2013-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  AND to_date('2013-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
; --  <- Here
SELECT
  JOBS.STARTED_DATE,
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, 
  JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.HOURS 
FROM JOBS, JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS 
WHERE 
  JOBS.STARTED_TIME BETWEEN to_date('2013-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
  AND to_date('2013-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND JOB_SCHEDULE_TECHNICIANS.JOB = JOBS.JOB
```

Comment: Same thing happens when I add the semicolon.  It looks like Dmitry found the problem.  I'm using Oracle 8i